# Package iOS ipa file from FlashDevelop - how to include external swfs in the ipa?

Tags: iphone, ios, actionscript-3

I plan to load external swfs in my iOS app written in ActionScript 3 FlashDevelop.

When I package it for ipa, is there a place in the settings where I need to include the
swf so it gets packaged with the ipa?

Is it in the settings xml file?

Or do I simply need to compile as it is?

Mirza

Comment: [External hosting of secondary SWFs for AIR apps on iOS](http://blogs.adobe.com/airodynamics/2013/03/08/external-hosting-of-secondary-swfs-for-air-apps-on-ios/) might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, my adobe flash is in portuguese, but I'll try to help.
Click file then AIR configuration for IOS. should be the third option from the bottom up. In the first tab at the bottom has a frame, all the files in this table will be add to the IPA.